# XPages: Observer and Observable

Tags: java, xpages

I've been trying to use Java Observer and Observable in a multi-user XPages application, but I'm running into identity conflicts. I'll explain.

Say A and B have the same view on their screens, a list of documents with Readers fields. We want to keep those screens synchronised as much as possible. If A changes something, B might be receiving updates, depending on his rights and roles. We achieved to do this using WebSockets, but I want to see if there's a better way, i.e. without send a message to the client telling it to re-fetch the screen.

Using the Observer mechanism, B can observe changes and push the changed screen to the user. The tricky part here is that if I call notifyObservers as user A, and I walk through all the observables, A will be executing the `Observer.update()` method, and not B.

I also thought of using a Timer-like solution, but I'd probably end up with the same conflicts.

Question: is there **any** way I can properly switch sessions in XPages? Or should I wait for Publish/Subscribe in the XPages server?

Comment: I would love to see a blog post on your websockets solution 

Comment: Hehe, I could do that indeed... just to give a few quick hints: Redis, Jedis, socket.io, node.js, server-client comm only. Credits to Andrew Hook (his website has vanished, no idea why).

Comment: stomp with/over sock-js would also solve your problem, but indirectly it also uses websockets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see 3 possible actions:

- Use the SudoUtils from [XPages-Scaffolding](https://github.com/jesse-gallagher/XPages-Scaffolding) to run code on behalf
- Use [DominoJNA](https://github.com/klehmann/domino-jna) to access the data with a different user id (not for the faint of heart)
- Just notify the client using the websocket - preferably via webworker. It then would make a fetch (the artist formerly known as Ajax) to see if changes are needed in the client UI. While this has the disadvantage of incurring a network interlude (websocket + fetch) it has the advantage that you don't need to mess with impersonisation which always carries the risk of something going wrong.

For the first two I would want to pack them into an OSGi bundle to be independent from the particularities of Java loaded from an NSF

### Old answer

> Your observer needs to be in an application context, so you can update any Observer. The observer then would use a websocket to the client to tell it: update this ONE record.
>   The tricky part, needs planning: have individual websocket addresses, so you notify only the ones that need notification

Comment: I can reach all Observables, I stored them globally, in application context. Only, user A has to use notifyObservers in his context, and that results in the Observer being called by A and not by B in his context. If I have to evaluate() some formula, it should be done by B, in his context and with his access rights etc. I want to make sure something really changed before sending the message out to the client(s).

Comment: ODA can also handle impersonation, most likely through the same means as SudoUtils. With XOTS that can then be delegated to another thread.
The problem with all of these impersonation approaches is you then need to send the result back to the relevant browser, if still available and if still on the relevant page.

Comment: I had hoped there is something like session communication based on PubSub or some other event-based system to wakeup the server-side without client intervention, so I can push notifications out signalling real changes. I think, for the time being, I'll stick to my websockets and let the clients re-fetch the content they need. And using a webworker approach might not be such a daft idea indeed... :-) Thanks all!